# Calling a function that takes a reference to an array twice

Tags: c++

I have a function that converts a decimal integer to binary and stores the result in a char array of size 32 (padded with zeros):

```
void ConvertToBinary(int DecimalNumber,char (&binNumber)[32])
{
    int dec = DecimalNumber;

    for(int pos = 31; pos >= 0; --pos)
    {
        binNumber[pos] = '0';
    }

    binNumber[32] = '\0';

    for(int pos = 31; pos >= 1; --pos)
    {
        if(dec % 2) {
            binNumber[pos] = '1';
        }
        dec = dec/2;
     }

}
```

However, when I call the function twice on two different arrays, the first array gets erased:

```
int main()
{

    char binArray1[32],binArray2[32];
    int dec1 = 89789879;
    int dec2 = 80809765;
    ConvertToBinary(dec1,binArray1);
    printf("binArray1: %s\n",binArray1); //Correctly prints out the array.
    ConvertToBinary(dec2,binArray2);
    printf("binArray1: %s\n",binArray1); //Prints out nothing :(
    printf("binArray2: %s\n",binArray2); //Prints out binArray2


return 0;
}
```

After researching the question, I think the problem has something to do with passing a reference to an array as an argument. But it's not clear to me why this should cause `binNumber1` to point to a different address.

Interestingly, I have been compiling using gcc version 4.1.2 on a Red-Hat (x86) Linux machine. When I compile and run on Visual Studio 2015, I do not get this problem. Any idea what is going on here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Errr, just pass the pointer.

Comment: Not an answer, just an observation.  If you remove the if in the second loop, the first loop is unnecessary since you would write every location in the array in the second loop.

Comment: Not getting a blank [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a779b752553f4078) but it is doubling up the output.

Comment: Obligatory "use `std::string` instead of `char *`" comment, too.

Comment: @erip Pass the pointer? You mean replace the &binArray argument with *binArray? I just tried that and it didn't work.

Comment: @erip.  This approach means that the caller can't pass a pointer to a 31 character buffer and get a problem with buffer overruns.

Comment: @MartinBonner It doesn't matter because his for-loops are hard-coded.

Comment: @erip:  `void broken() { char buf[1]; ConvertToBinary(0,buf); }`  As currently defined this is a compile error.  If `ConvertToBinary` takes a pointer, it's a buffer overrun.  I prefer compile time errors to undefined behaviour.

Comment: `binNumber[32] = '\0';` Whoops....

Answer (score 6):

The `%s` directive for `printf` is for printing null-terminated strings of characters. Your arrays are *not* null-terminated, so you should not output them using `%s`.

Instead, you could just print them in a loop:

```
for (auto c : binArray1) std::cout << c;
```

Comment: While this is a very good answer :), may I kindly suggest to use auto&& in the loop?

Comment: Or print a limited number of characters - with "%.32s".

Comment: ... or make the buffer 33 characters and add a nul-terminator.

Comment: Thanks all of you for the answers. However, even after editing my post and null-terminating the char array, I am still getting the same result.

Comment: @SergeyA Overkill, hahaha.

Comment: @SergeyA I don't think forwarding references are really necessary for printing `int`s, but maybe that's just my opinion.

Comment: @TartanLlama, my view is following: if you introspect into what binArray actually is, you might as well have your c strongly typed, `char c: binArray1`. Nothing wrong with that. Now, using auto there makes for a good muscle memory, but as muscle memory, auto&& is preferred over auto.

Answer (score 3):

```
binNumber[32] = '\0';
```

`binNumber` is an array of 32 `char`s. `binNumber[32]` is not a valid index into that array, so the assignment to it produces undefined behavior. To hold 32 characters and a terminating zero, the arrays should have size 33.

Comment: Thanks Pete Becker. Now it works! Thank you everyone for their input.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that you have 32 digits, which in this case you do, you can use

```
printf("binArray1: %.32s\n",binArray1);
```

to print only the first 32 characters.